# Can't combine navigators

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with my React Native application.

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrdxj.jpg)

[Other tab example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFEia.jpg)

I would like for the first screenshot to have only one header instead of two here and keep the tab navigator, but when clicking the "Mentions légales" button, to be redirected to the CGUScreen, with a header like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7FPJ.png), and without the tab navigator at the bottom.

BottomTabNavigator.js :

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import * as React from 'react';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import OffresScreen from '../screens/OffresScreen';
import PlusScreen from '../screens/PlusScreen';
import CGUScreen from '../screens/CGUScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const CGUStack = createStackNavigator();

export default function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {

  navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route) });

  function CGUStackScreen() {
   return (
     <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <CGUStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Plus">
        <CGUStack.Screen name="Plus" component={PlusScreen} />
        <CGUStack.Screen name="CGU" component={CGUScreen} />
      </CGUStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={'Home'}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Catalogues',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-book" />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Offres"
        component={OffresScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Offres',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-flash" />
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Plus"
        component={CGUStackScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Plus',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-menu" />,
          navigationOptions: {
            headerMode: 'none',
          }
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  const routeName = route.state?.routes[route.state.index]?.name ?? 'Home';

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Home':
      return 'Catalogues';
    case 'Plus':
      return 'Plus';
    case 'Offres':
      return 'Offres';
    case 'CGU':
      return 'CGU';
  }
}
```

And in my App.js, I have:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
<NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
 <Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
 </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

I don't really understand what goes wrong with my code. And how can I from the PlusScreen.js make the button redirect to CGUScreen?
Thanks for your help! :)

UPDATE : I now have the navigation working, but it keeps the second header title and the bottom tabs.

UPDATE 2 : It works, using the stack navigator in the App.js instead of creating another one in the Tab Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

```
<BottomTab.Screen
    name="Plus"
    component={CGUStackScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Plus',
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-menu" />,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: 'none',
        tabBarVisible: false,  //<---- Here hide tabbar in CGUStackScreen
      }
    }}
```